# Use of serialized target queues for Concurrent queues in iOS

Tags: ios, concurrency, queue

I was going through this excellent blog post
(http://www.humancode.us/2014/08/14/target-queues.html)
of target threads in iOS and I could not help but wonder why do we need such a mechanism. In the example, we are specifying a serialised target queue for a custom concurrent queue. Can we not achieve the same by executing the blocks in the original concurrent queue in a serialised queue instead?

Whats the point of having a serialised target queue for a concurrent queue????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got You right, you're asking why would someone start serial task on a concurrent queue.

You would need that kind of behaviour in case, if most tasks with some resource can be performed concurrently (aka, simultaneously), but some tasks are, by nature, unsafe to be performed concurrently with others.

The most common example is readers/writers problem. Here you are accessing, for example, some resource of a file system. It's ok to read it even from different threads - every reader will get exactly what it needs. But here comes necessity to update contents of that file. Modifying it while someone reads it leads to unpredicted results - reader is not guaranteed to get the right, expected, info (partially from old version, partially from new). Even worse - there can be two writers (if file contents changes by application user and from some central storage via net) - result will be some crazy mix of two versions (actually, it can be now even corrupted)

Here comes necessity for each writer to wait till all other tasks performed (no one reads, no one writes), and for each reader to wait until no writing tasks take place (no one writes, no matter how many readers)

Wikipedia has nice article on this one. I haven't run into any other practical situations, where you would need this, but I believe there're more of them.

Hope it answers your question

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think yes, you understood my query, but a few concerns remain. When you say serial task, don't you mean an operation/block/job that is executed serially?

Comment: In the classic Readers/Writers problem, can I not, serialise the whole read and write operations on the file/resource rather through a serial queue than creating a concurrent queue, then specifying its target queue as serial such that all the read, write operations are serialised. Your example makes total sense, but just wondering why am I doing the serialization through a concurrent task only to achieve serialisation when I can do the same directly. Makes sense???

Comment: Well, yes. In case of GCD, I mean block. But in general - any operation/block/task/job.

Comment: In the blog I mentioned there is a line which states "In essence, a serial target queue can serialize a concurrent queue.". Therein lies my doubt...why bother with a concurrent queue when I can use a serial queue directly. Thanks for your help

Comment: Second question makes me think I got You wrong. Actually, I can't think of how can you "serialise the whole read and write operations on file". It is possible only in some object responsible for file access. Concurrent queue gives you possibility to read simultaneously (have multiply readers at one moment). In your proposal you will restrict only one reader access till he finishes. If it's ok for your task (few readers, short reading time) - go for it

Comment: Yep, that line is strange for me too. Have to think of it. 
You're welcome

Comment: Exactly! What you said makes perfect sense. Serialising the reader/writer problem is a waste of concurrency. But coming back to the original question, if I am starting serial tasks on a concurrent queue, is it not the same i.e serial access to a file?

Comment: Anyway...getting late at my end :) Need a caffeine boost. Do share your findings here if you discover something interesting. Thanks again and cheers.

Comment: Think, I get to the point. You're absolutely right - you can achieve the same just targeting serial queue. However, it comes in handy, when you need to synchronise concurrent queues you don't own. Some access manager (to critical resource) provides you with serial access queue which becomes target queue for your concurrently starting tasks. For example - several http-connection handlers each with its own concurrent handle queue. Each new response initiates access to some folder - it is synchronised by access manager. And you don't care, that your blocks will actually execute in a serial manner

Comment: Actualy, that is what said at the end of the article =)

Comment: @Sergii...Yaah that makes sense..Especially when you don't own certain queues. But you want your operation to be serially executed on those. Thanks